# Use background image in HTML header

Tags: html, css, jsf

[image]

I have a requirement where I need to display an image on top of the panelGrid as a header. Just wanted to know if this is possible. At present I am using a styeClass but the header image is not aligned properly with the panelGrid.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="width: 320pt;margin: 0 auto;padding-bottom:10pt;padding-left:10pt;" styleClass="fooheader" >
```

The style being used :

```
.fooheader {
background: url(../img/foo.png) no-repeat;
width: 395px;
height: 73px;
}
```

foo.png dimensions : 395 X 68

Please find the HTML generated content below :

```
                                <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><table class="fooheader" style="width: 320pt;margin: 0 auto;padding-bottom:10pt;padding-left:10pt;">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><span style="color:white;font-weight:bold;">PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS</span></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><table width="100%">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><div id="MainForm:j_idt19" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width: 300pt;height: 250pt;margin: 0 auto;border-top:none;"><div id="MainForm:j_idt19_content" class="ui-panel-content ui-widget-content"><table class="foo-icon-user">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: CSS works on HTML, not on JSF. In order to get better answers from CSS experts, please show the JSF-generated HTML output instead of the JSF source code and retag the question from `[jsf]` to `[html]` and reformulate the title as "Use background image in HTML <th>" or so. Once you got the answer, it's piece of cake to rewrite the original JSF source code in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML output.

Comment: Wouldn't it help to put the image into a `<f:facet name="header">` inside the `<h:panelGrid>`?

Comment: The unprofessional childish yelling `PLEASE HELP ME WITH THIS` is a huge demotivator. I recommend to just leave it out. In any way, I don't see any `<th>` in the generated HTML output. Essentially, you don't have a table header at all. This in turn suggests that you haven't declared a table header in `<h:panelGrid>` at all. Why not? As long as you don't let JSF generate the right HTML, it would not be possible to apply the desired CSS.